# Get response from google search with python

Tags: python, google-chrome, search

I am trying to get text from a search on google. My idea is that iam searching with python in the normal google search and then print out the text that is on the right site next to the search results. But the code i found doesnt work.

---

```
from googlesearch import search
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def google_search(query):
    results = search(query, num_results=1)
    for result in results:
        response = requests.get(result)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        answer = soup.find('div', class_='kno-rdesc')
        if answer:
            return answer.text
response = google_search("Was ist die Hauptstadt von Deutschland")
print(response)
```

So basicaly it should give back the right box, which you can find sometimes on the right site. I hope somebody can help. Thx

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Done, thank you, didnt saw that